# Storing data to Room database

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a question that,

Let's consider we have a app in which we are adding many categories (ex: shopping,study,public, etc..)  at runtime , there is no limit of adding categories since we adding it at runtime while we use the app  and storing in a **RoomDatabase** having  one Entity class and Dao.

-> now my question arises here , In that categories(ex: shopping,study,public, etc..) there are lot of different items we will store , so how can we use **Roomdatabase** to store all these categories item .

so that when we will open the shopping category so it will show only shopping list and so on for other categories

**Is it possible to save all data of these categories?** ,since we are adding many categories and there sub data then how it is possible to make that much of **DAO** and **ENTITY CLASS**  to save that much of sub data.

-> If we will use **SHARED PREFENCES** . then we can store all categories sub data into a unique keys(unique key can be a categories name). so if we add more and more categories then it will store data to categories unique name.

but how can we do in roomDatabase. Is it possible? if yes then how....?

i hope, i explained my question  well

**Dao Interface**

```
@Dao
 interface Dao {

@Insert
fun insert(studentName: StudentsEntity): Long

@Insert
fun stdDetailsInsert(stdDetails: StudentDetailsEntity)

@Transaction
@Query("Select * from Student")
fun getAllStudent(): MutableList<WholeDataStudent>

@Query("Select * from Student")
fun getStudentName(): MutableList<StudentsEntity>

}
```

**Entity Class**

```
@Entity(tableName = "Student")
data class StudentsEntity(
val stdName: String
) {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
var stdId: Int = 0
}

@Entity
data class StudentDetailsEntity(

val detailsId: Int,
val stdAddress: String,
val phoneNo: String
) {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
var id: Int = 0
}

data class WholeDataStudent(
@Embedded val std: StudentsEntity,

@Relation(
    parentColumn = "stdId",
    entityColumn = "detailsId",
    entity = StudentDetailsEntity::class
)

val stdDetails: List<StudentDetailsEntity>
)
```

Comment: You can try creating a table for category. like it''s column would be id, categoryName, noOfItems and any other column that you would like to add.

Comment: there is no limit of categories since we adding it at runtime while we use the app ,so how it can store data in categories that is different for all data in other categories . Is it so confusing @Akash Bisht

Comment: Ok.. so you want to add category that may have different type of data for it?  May be you can go for nosql database.

Comment: yes ,correct @Akash Bisht. Categories will be adding when we are using app so there is no limit to it so how it's possible to save all different categories data , since we have only one DAO and Entitiy class . and  we can't make it every time when we are adding categories.

Comment: I dont have a concept of nosql . Is it possible from Room database that's my question, if it's possible then how

Comment: ok. I don't know if its a good way or not. you can have a table(entity) with categoryName, and data(string type would do) and in data you add object details as a json string, this way whenever you get data of particular category you could parse json string to it's object model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220567/discussion-between-akash-bisht-and-kaunain).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your items in your different categories, can these items use the same `Item` Entity class template?
I can think of solutions for both scenarios.

Without further information, let me give you an idea for supporting adding categories (and corresponding items) dynamically and a **common** item class for all items.

Room (based on SQL) offers several ways of to define [data relationships](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships).

As far as I understand your problem:

- **one** category can have **many** items
- but **each** item belongs only to **one** category

If that holds true, then you have a [**one-to-many** relationship](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#one-to-many) in your data.

What Akash Bisht was pointing at: you should have another entity for your categories.
There, at minimum you need to store information such as the ID (primary key) and the name (string) of that category.
Then you can create categories dynamically and add them to this table. This can be as many categories as you want.
Then when creating your items inside this category, you just need to add the ID reference of the corresponding category in the `Item` entity, e.g. as a variable like `categoryId`

On the other hand you could also just store the category name directly in the Item entity. But this has the disadvantage that when you want to change, for example, your categories name, then you have to update all your items.

To then just get the items for one specific category, as you stated as requirements, you have at least 2 options:

1. write a SQL query that only selects items of a specific category
2. or you query a list of all your items and then filter them by a category

If your data for different categories is of types that can be stored in shared preferences (as you have mentioned). You also can handle that with this approach.

Comment: hey @cewaphi i did what you said and this is what i wanted but but, problem is I am not able to fetch user unique data to another activity after clicking on user name . here i'm using one to one reationship. can you please suggest how can i fetch all student  unique data

Comment: @Kaunain what exactly are you trying to accomplish? What do you mean by "fetching to another activity"? You want to pass the student id to another activity in a bundle and then get the details for this student (ID) in this new activity?

Comment: i have two activity  , in the first activity I am adding student name and to every student  i am giving details in another activity  . so every student have different data . i used one to one relationship . code is given in question . everything is perfect  i  checked it through loging but i am not able to apply logic to add these student data in another activty . @cewaphi

Comment: as you said above to do by one to one ralationship . i did same and its worked but i am not able to show the data . how can i show it   @cewaphi

Comment: As you can see i used two entities class for student name and student details and onr data class to relate them .  then i checked it in my app by calling this from DAO  @Transaction
@Query("Select * from Student") fun getAllStudent(): MutableList<WholeDataStudent>   .    Its working fine but what should i do to  display these data in recylerView(i am using to display these data)

Comment: Sorry i dont have any idea , how to do this. I dont know i am able to understand you or not :(

Comment: Will a student always only have a one to one relationship with the student details? Then I wonder if you really need another entity for that. You could have all that inside of your student class? Is there a specific reason why you are using a 'MutableList' here instead of 'List'?

Comment: Do you know how to implement a recycler view and it's view holder? First you need to submit a list to your recycler view and notify the adapter about the changes. Then on the 'onBindViewHolder' you pass the data of your student to the view holder and let it be displayed in it's view. I'm not sure where exactly you are stuck in your implementation

Comment: any way Thanks for your suggestion . one to one relation solved my problem.  @cewaphi